# Instalment payments with ubercart

Tags: 6, ubercart

I'm building a student application on which we have the requirement that student can pay its fees via instalment.I have googled around the same but I does not found how to achieve it.Does there any existing module for to achieve the similar functionality.If you have any ideas then do let me know how to achieve this.
The instalment payment will be charged only in two instalments(first instalment and second instalment).The amount of the first instalment can be vary from second instalment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [UC Down Payment](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_downpayment) module for this task.

> This module allows Ubercart store administrators to add partial payment functionality as a product feature. They can assign down payment amount and the due date to any product, and manage down payments and partially paid orders in the admin section.